# What is the underlying vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that a matrix represents a  linear maps between two vector spaces, now when we think of $A+\lambda B$ where $\lambda$ is a complex variable and $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$

For example, $C=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 2\lambda\\ 1+\lambda & 5+\lambda \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &0\\1 & 5\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}=A+\lambda B$

is a matrix pencil.

My question is: what are possible vector spaces on which I can create/find/ (there are) linear maps for representing those linear maps I will get entries as linear polynomials in my matrix?

What are the elements of kernel of $A+\lambda B$ in general? will they be vectors of the form $(p_1,\dots,p_n)$ where $p_i$'s are linear polynomial?

Or, I should think simply like this:  $A,B$ are linear maps on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we are just considering a linear polynomials with coefficients from $M_n(\mathbb{R})$